# Connect to open LDAP over ssl

Tags: c#, openldap

I am working on a website which is used to reset password of LDAP users. I am not able to make connection with server over ssl. I tried various code and authentication types.

This is what used on server for connectivity with LDAP on which website is hosted. I also tested it with both ssl ports. 636 and 3269.

```
0 = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_ENCRYPT, 1)
res = ldap_bind_s(ld, NULL, &NtAuthIdentity?, NEGOTIATE (1158)); v.3

{NtAuthIdentity?: User='_ldapuser'; Pwd='unavailable';; domain = 'SJTPNOC.DOMAIN'}
```

I am using following code in website

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("SJTP.DOMAIN",636));

connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;

connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;

connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential("CN=user,CN=Users,DC=SJTPNOC,DC=DOMAIN", "password","CN=Users,DC=SJTPNOC,DC=DOMAIN");

connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer=true;

connection.Bind();
```

Getting exception "LDAP server is unavailable". I tried that code with 389 port
and without ssl and it's working fine.

Please let me know what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only want encryption and do not need strong authentication of the ldap server, maybe you should add :

```
connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate =
                new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
```

Comment: Now I have to reset user password

Comment: I used replace operation on userPassword but getting error "The server cannot handle directory requests.".

Comment: @mayank.karki you should close this question and give a detailed description of your new problem in a new question.

Comment: Link of my new question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635484
/reset-ldap-user-password-error-the-server-cannot-handle-directory-requests
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi jbl, I have one more query.This is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908745/find-out-user-cannot-change-password-value-of-ldap    .Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hi jbl I am stuck some where and need your help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437986/property-value-returned-by-directorysearcher-and-searchresponse-are-of-different)

Answer (score 4):

I also had a problem connecting via SSL, but not over plaintext.  I did some network sniffing and was able to see that although I set the LdapConnection.AuthType to Basic, my client machine was finding and using client certificates for the SSL handshake.  The certificate it found (don't know if I should be mad at VisualStudio or the .NET LdapConnection class) was a cheesy self-signed cert that the LDAP server did not like.  It returned a very secure "server unavailable" error; good for it.  So there is a client certificate resolver delegate in the SessionOptions I needed to provide with a very simple implementation:

```
public static X509Certificate ClientCertFinder(LdapConnection connection,
                                                byte[][] trustedCAs)
{
   return null;
}
```

Then, set the SessionOptions QueryClientCertificateCallback delegate to use the stub like this:

```
connection.SessionOptions.QueryClientCertificate =
      new QueryClientCertificateCallback(ClientCertFinder);
```

You could probably even make this a oneliner as in @jbl's answer for the validation callback, but maybe some day I'll want to do client-certificate-authentication, and having that stub serves as a reminder for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me to connect to AD using LDAPS

```
ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("your.LDAPSserver.com", 636));

var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("UsernameWithoutDomain", "yourPassword", "AD.yourDOMAIN.com");
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ServerCallback);
ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
        
SearchRequest Srchrequest = new SearchRequest("CN=Users,DC=AD,DC=YOURCOMPANY,DC=COM", "mail=useremail@company.com", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
SearchResponse SrchResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(Srchrequest);
```

// ServerCallback

```
private static bool ServerCallback(LdapConnection connection, X509Certificate certificate)
{
    return true;
}
```

Surprisingly it is also working when I am not using **networkCredential** and just using **ldapConnection.Bind();** Seems it is using my local credentials as default on my local machine.