# Reset ldap user password (Error : The server cannot handle directory requests. )

Tags: c#-4.0, openldap

I am using this code:

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("DOMAIN",636));

connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate =
            new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential("CN=user,CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN","password!");

connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer=true;

using(connection)
{
  connection.Bind();

  SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("CN=Users,DC=DOMAIN", "CN=mayank",    System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);

  SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);

  SearchResultEntry entry = response.Entries[0];

  DirectoryAttributeModification modifyUserPassword = new DirectoryAttributeModification();
        modifyUserPassword.Operation = DirectoryAttributeOperation.Replace;
        modifyUserPassword.Name = "unicodePwd";
        modifyUserPassword.Add(GetPasswordData("admin1234!"));

        ModifyRequest modifyRequest = new ModifyRequest(entry.DistinguishedName, modifyUserPassword);
        DirectoryResponse dirResponse = connection.SendRequest(modifyRequest);
```

}

This successfully connects to LDAP but when one attempts to change the password, it throws an error stating "The server cannot handle directory requests."

Comment: Have you tried removing the Bind() and SearchRequest and passing directly the entry Dn to the modifyRequest (you have it, since you are doing your searchrequest with it).

Comment: Also, my code (CentOsDS) uses the userpassword attribute (no base64 involved), not the unicodepwd attribute

Comment: Thanks now its working fine. I have one more query, I have to check that user account is locked or not.

Comment: on CentOS DS, it's boolean nsaccountlock attribute of entry. Lock because of too many failed attempts can be checked with int attribute passwordretrycount, which can not be greater or equal than the max authorized failed retries for login