# Find out User cannot change password value of ldap

Tags: c#, openldap

I am trying to find out that in ad, user has allowed to change password or not. 
I have used SearchResponse to find out that user exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

SearchResponse response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(request);
                DirectoryAttribute attribute = response.Entries[0].Attributes["ntSecurityDescriptor"];

```
            if (attribute != null)
            {
                const string PASSWORD_GUID = "{ab721a53-1e2f-11d0-9819-00aa0040529b}";
                const int ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT = 6;
                bool fEveryone = false;
                bool fSelf = false;

                ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility secUtility = new ActiveDs.ADsSecurityUtility();
                ActiveDs.IADsSecurityDescriptor sd = (IADsSecurityDescriptor)secUtility.ConvertSecurityDescriptor((byte[])attribute[0], (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_RAW, (int)ADS_SD_FORMAT_ENUM.ADS_SD_FORMAT_IID);
                ActiveDs.IADsAccessControlList acl = (ActiveDs.IADsAccessControlList)sd.DiscretionaryAcl;

                foreach (ActiveDs.IADsAccessControlEntry ace in acl)
                {
                    if ((ace.ObjectType != null) && (ace.ObjectType.ToUpper() == PASSWORD_GUID.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        if ((ace.Trustee == "Everyone") && (ace.AceType == ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT))
                        {
                            fEveryone = true;
                        }
                        if ((ace.Trustee == @"NT AUTHORITY\SELF") && (ace.AceType == ADS_ACETYPE_ACCESS_DENIED_OBJECT))
                        {
                            fSelf = true;
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (fEveryone || fSelf)
                {
                    return Global.RequestContants.CANT_CHANGE_PASSWORD;
                }
                else
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
```