# Connect to LDAP over ssl from remote machine using "DirectoryEntry" API

Tags: c#, ssl, openldap, directoryentry

I need to connect to LDAP over SSL from **a remote machine**; There are many discussions for this, but the solutions posted in them do work only in the same Windows Server domain machine; The same code fails to connect successfully from a remote machine;

Code I tried:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://fqdn:636/DC=aa,DC=bb", "username", "password");
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
searcher.SearchRoot = entry;
searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))";
SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
```

To say again, I am able to get results from same WindowsServer domain machine; But I get exception **"Server is not operational"** when I try the same code from remote machine;

I found that its due to certificate validation failure i.e. Windows Server's certificate is not validated in remote machine; But I don't know how to override certificate validation for 'DirectoryEntry object';

- This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621256/connect-to-open-ldap-over-ssl) has solution for Certificate issue; But its for 'LdapConnection'
- But I need the solution for **DirectoryEntry** API;

Just for an info; This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351752/certificate-unknown-on-client-while-connecting-to-ldap-over-ssl) has the same question raised for Java with no answers; My requirement is for **C#**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no certificate override available for `DirectoryEntry`.

You have to use the lower-level `LdapConnection` and `LdapDirectoryIdentifier` classes from the [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DirectoryServices.Protocols(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace.

It shouldn't be too difficult to convert your code over, and in doing so, you'll be able to handle both local and remote directory resources. I ran into this same issue a while ago, and I wrote up an extensive post on why this is the case, and how to work around it - check it out :

[Set callback for System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry to handle self-signed SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911391/set-callback-for-system-directoryservices-directoryentry-to-handle-self-signed-s/13073365#13073365)