# Invalid credentials on ldap-bind with password having ü

Tags: c#, ldap, ldapconnection

I'm performing a bind to a ldap-server using the class LdapConnection. In case of a "normal" password it works fine. But if the user has a password including ü, ä or ö the server returns an error INVALID CREDENTIALS. I assumed an encoding issue but cannot find any settings .NET-classes. Therefore I had a look at the network traffic I found out that the letter 'ü' is represented in hex by 'fc'. Using a ldap-browser the 'ü' is presented by 'c3bc'.

```
var identifier = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("myserver", 389);

var dn = "...";
var passwort = "withÜ";
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(dn, password);
var connection = new LdapConnection(identifier, credentials, AuthType.Basic);
connection.Bind(credentials);
```

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 1):

The Unicode codepoint for `ü` is hex FC as you state.  However, LDAP uses either ASCII or UTF-8 when encoding, where `ü` in UTF-8 is represented as HEX C3BC.

[LDAP v3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366099(v=vs.85).aspx) allows use of UTF-8.

```
connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
```

However you have a **major security hole** in that the user name and password and being passed in the clear.  You should use SSL/TLS.  See [Connect to open LDAP over ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12621256/connect-to-open-ldap-over-ssl).

Comment: Thanks for SSL-hint. SSL is disabled temporarily for easier investigation of network traffic ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `LdapConnestion`'s `SessionOptions` `ProtocolVersion` to **3**.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80ffb301-b088-4764-818a-80628bd40415/ldap-connection-to-sun-ldap-with-umlauts?forum=netfxnetcom):

> The german umlaut was not correctly transported because of protocol version "2" on the LdapConnection's LdapSessionOptions class. 
>   After setting the protocol version to "3" on the LdapSessionOptions class, the request returned results as expected!